# Difference of two sequences approaches to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I come across a statement that if the absolute value of difference of two sequences approaches to zero, then they are both converges or both diverges. It looks very correct to me, but I cannot think of a good formal proof for it.

Answer (score 2):

Nicolas Agote has posted a complete solution above, but more generally this is a good kind of "follow your nose" proof in analysis that usually rely on a similar set of strategies. In particular when faced with this problem, try:

- Recalling the definitions (of convergence and divergence)
- Assume a contradiction if needed
- Adding and subtracting the same terms doesn't affect equality but allows you to group "close" terms (groups you know something about)
- The triangle inequality allows you to break those groups apart and draw conclusions

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your sequences are $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. It is enough to show that if $(a_n)_n$ converges then $(b_n)_n$ converges (because if $(a_n)_n$ does not converge then $(b_n)_n$ cannot converge as with an analogous proof it would imply $(a_n)_n$ to converge which is a contradiction).

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$. Then we have that:

$|b_n - L| = |b_n - a_n + a_n - L| \leq |b_n - a_n| + |a_n - L|$

where both terms go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

This trick of "splitting" a distance into many small distances with the triangular inequality helps in lots of proofs so it is one to keep in mind.